# Cypress flaky testing

Tags: typescript, frontend, cypress

i am testing the frontend of [this webhsop](https://www.humanic.net/de) with Cypress. There is a particular test which only fails on this tenant and never does on the others (There are 5 tenants for different countries). But it's not that it fails all the time, it just does sometimes and I can't figure out why this happens.

Here's what the test should do:

1. Visit the homepage
2. Visit a product page
3. Pick a size that is available
4. Put the product in the shoppingcart
5. Repeat steps 2-4
6. Check if the cart amount is '2'

The Problem:

- The cart amount **sometimes** is only 1 and I can't determine why

My assumptions:

- I think the cart amount is lost when visiting the second product page
- It has something to do with not accepting the cookies (I don't want to accept the cookies)

Notes:

- All the other tenants are the same as the one I am having troubles with except for the language

This is the test:

```
describe('[anon] add to cart ' + baseUrl, () => {
  if (!features.shoppingCartFeature) return;

  const homepage         = new Homepage();
  const productpage      = new ProductPage();
  const shoppingCartPage = new ShoppingCartPage();

  const testProduct  = Cypress.env('testProduct');
  const testProduct2 = Cypress.env('testProduct2');

  beforeEach(() => {
    homepage.visit();
  });

  it('add to cart as anomymous user for 2 products', () => {
    productpage.visitProduct(testProduct.productID);
    productpage.add2Cart(true);

    productpage.visitProduct(testProduct2.productID);
    productpage.add2Cart(true);

   shoppingCartPage.checkCartAmount(2);
  });

});
```

This is the product page

```
class ProductPage extends BasePage {
  visitProduct(id) {
    // intercept this api call, bc after the response the size selection is available
    cy.intercept(personalizeUrl).as('sizes');
    cy.visit(baseUrl + `/p/` + id);
    cy.wait('@sizes');
    return this;
  }

  add2Cart(has_size) {
    if (has_size) {
      this.pickSize();
      cy.get(selectors.pdp_add2CartBtn).click();
    } else {
      cy.get(selectors.pdp_add2CartBtn).click();
    }
    cy.checkForPopup();
  }

  /**
   * iterate over the dropdown menu and choose the first size that is not sold out
   */
  pickSize() {
    cy.get(selectors.pdp_chooseSizeBtn).click();
    cy.get(selectors.pdp_sizes).each(($size_elem) => {
      if (
        !$size_elem.text().includes(Cypress.env('soldOutText')) &&
        !$size_elem.text().includes(Cypress.env('onlyInShopText'))
      ) {
        cy.wrap($size_elem).click();
        return false; // has to return false to stop iterating
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Thx in advance!

Comment: Network issues can play a big role if your tests are sometimes passing and other times not.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding an assertion every time a new page loads. This can be anything to make sure that the page has completely loaded before the test continues.
Basically when you navigate to the home page you can say:

`cy.contains('COOL SNEAKERS FOR COOL KIDS).should('be.visible)`

Do this for every new page you navigate to so  that you know the page is done loading before the tests continue.